# How to lock dataframe that consistently satisfy condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, filter, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe and I'm trying to script to print the number "5" under the time column, "5" being the value where "col" consistently stays at 1.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col': [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
print(df)

   time  col
0     1    0
1     2    1
2     3    0
3     4    0
4     5    1
5     6    1
6     7    1
7     8    1
8     9    1
9    10    1
```

What'd be a good way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are looking for something like this:

```
cond1=df['col'].shift().ffill().eq(df.loc[df['col'].eq(1),'col'])
cond2=(cond1.eq(False))&(cond1.shift(-1).eq(True))
df['time']=df['time'].where(cond2|(~cond1)).ffill().fillna(df['time'])
```

---

```
print(df)
   time  col
0   1.0    0
1   2.0    1
2   3.0    0
3   4.0    0
4   5.0    1
5   5.0    1
6   5.0    1
7   5.0    1
8   5.0    1
9   5.0    1
```

**Explanation:**

Using cond1 you select values that have to be replaced

```
print(cond1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Using cond2 you select the value with which it should be replaced

```
print(cond2)


0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

to real dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 'col': [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
cond1=df['col'].shift().ffill().eq(df.loc[df['col'].eq(1),'col'])
print(df)

    time  col
0      1    0
1      2    0
2      3    0
3      4    1
4      5    1
5      6    1
6      7    0
7      8    0
8      9    0
9     10    0
10    11    0
11    12    1
12    13    1
13    14    1
14    15    1
15    16    1
16    17    1
17    18    1
18    19    1
19    20    1

cond1=df['col'].shift().ffill().eq(df.loc[df['col'].eq(1),'col'])
cond2=(cond1.eq(False))&(cond1.shift(-1).eq(True))
df['time']=df['time'].where(cond2|(~cond1)).ffill().fillna(df['time'])
print(df)


  time  col
0    1.0    0
1    2.0    0
2    3.0    0
3    4.0    1
4    4.0    1
5    4.0    1
6    7.0    0
7    8.0    0
8    9.0    0
9   10.0    0
10  11.0    0
11  12.0    1
12  12.0    1
13  12.0    1
14  12.0    1
15  12.0    1
16  12.0    1
17  12.0    1
18  12.0    1
19  12.0    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried cond1 however that wouldn't work with some slight variation of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the real dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 'col': [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
cond1=df['col'].shift().ffill().eq(df.loc[df['col'].eq(1),'col'])
df['cond1'] = cond1
print(df)

Output
    time  col  cond1
0      1    0  False
1      2    0  False
2      3    0  False
3      4    1  False
4      5    1   True
5      6    1   True
6      7    0  False
7      8    0  False
8      9    0  False
9     10    0  False
10    11    0  False
11    12    1  False
12    13    1   True
13    14    1   True
14    15    1   True
15    16    1   True
16    17    1   True
17    18    1   True
18    19    1   True
19    20    1   True
```

My intent is trying to pinpoint time 13.

Comment: only time13? or time 13 and time5?

Comment: Look at: to real DataFrame output

Comment: I do not understand why you want to add 13, in any case it would be 12. Before you wanted to add 5 because it was when the first 1 appeare

Comment: You're correct I was looking for 12 where it first appeared. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. please if you have no further questions, could you accept and / or vote my answer?